# Android java.lang.NullPointerException Crash Report

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have a question about this error.
So I just launch my application on google play and I got a lot of crash reports with detail like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at c.c.f.b.onPostExecute (:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:771)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900 (AsyncTask.java:199)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:788)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8218)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:626)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1015)
```

But when I test it on my device and emulator, I never got that crash or error.
There are some crash errors like that, but with different details.

I'm using Android Studio with Kotlin. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me to solve this error.

Thank you so much.

==============================

I have a single class called `DataApi.kt` and it is called once from `MainActivity.class`.
Inside the `DataApi.kt`, I override the `onPostExecute` method to save some data to `SharedPreference` that I need.

`DataAPI.kt`

```
class DataAPI : AsyncTask<String?, String?, String>() {
    val JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")
    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    fun DataAPI(context: Context) {
        mContext = context
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String? {
        /* some code */
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        try {
            val jObj = JSONObject(result)
            PreferenceConnector.clearShared(mContext)
            PreferenceConnector.writeString(
                mContext,
                PreferenceConnector.DOMAIN,
                jObj.getString("domain")
            )
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )

        var api = DataAPI()
        api.DataAPI(this)
        api.execute()
        Handler().postDelayed({ init() }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: About the `onPostExecute` you can check this code  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60289320/11835023

Comment: Your `doInBackground` can return nulls (`String?`) but `onPostExecute` expects nonnulls (`String`).

Comment: I agree with @laalto's comment, from the crash log `c.c.f.b.onPostExecute (:1)`  and the return value of `doInBackground` maybe is null, but `onPostExecute` only accept non-null String. Moreover, the param of `JSONObject(result)` expect non-null String, `JSONObject(@RecentlyNonNull String json)`

Answer (score 0):

Regards the `NPE`(NullPointerException), the crash report shows the crash in the method of `onPostExecute`

Maybe you use sth. View in `onPostExecute`, but you didn't initialize it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I update my question to add more detail about the flow that I'm implementing on my project. I didn't update View onPostExecute, I just save some data on SharedPreference